# Changing page lifecycle

Tags: asp.net

Which method does Page class invoke to instantiate its controls? I want to override it so as to be able to instantiate only certain controls.

Answer (score 1):

there is a nice explanation here: [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

an article like this is a must read if you do ASP.NET web form development.

just that you have some background before just palying around with Page_Load and Page_Init without a clue, in the article there is a table with the list of all events in the right order and full explanation for each of them.

Comment: The earliest lifecycle method described there is ProcessRequest. But ProcessRequest does not instantiate controls according to msdn library. And at the stage of OnPreInit all controls are already created.

Answer (score 0):

If your controls are not dynamically instantiated then **you can't** in the *normal* page lifecycle.

Comment: Yes, my controls are static and reside in aspx file. But there must be some way!

Comment: Yes there is a way, don't make them static. If they're in the aspx page they'll be instantiated. You'll make life very hard for yourself if you try to fiddle with the page instantiation. It would far better to out them in usercontrols & dynamically load the usercontrols.

Comment: Yes, Simon, in fact i started my answer with "If your controls are not dynamically instantiated"

Answer (score 0):

if you open reflector it has a function called :

loadControlRecursivly ( or something like that) - thats where he laods it.

Comment: i added the func from reflector

Answer (score 0):

here it is :

```
internal virtual void LoadRecursive()
{
    if (this._controlState < ControlState.Loaded)
    {
        if (this._adapter != null)
        {
            this._adapter.OnLoad(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            this.OnLoad(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
    if ((this._occasionalFields != null) && (this._occasionalFields.Controls != null))
    {
        string errorMsg = this._occasionalFields.Controls.SetCollectionReadOnly("Parent_collections_readonly");
        int count = this._occasionalFields.Controls.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            this._occasionalFields.Controls[i].LoadRecursive();
        }
        this._occasionalFields.Controls.SetCollectionReadOnly(errorMsg);
    }
    if (this._controlState < ControlState.Loaded)
    {
        this._controlState = ControlState.Loaded;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. I have to think:) I'm new to asp.net

Comment: Oh... It doesn't seem to instantiate controls, it rather sends them OnLoad event messages...